# Git throws 400 Bad Request when executed with sudo

Tags: git, sudo, http-status-code-400, bitbucket-server

There is a weird error that we have been getting.

I have compiled git 2.5.1 from source on Centos 6.5 where I also have Atlassian Stash running for the control and pushed the code into a repo. When I try to fetch or pull from the repo as a regular user or su everything works well. However when i use `sudo git fetch --all` it fails with `error: The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request while accessing http://stash.domain.com/scm/myr/myrepo.git/info/refs`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is it possible with sudo that you're running a different version of git? Perhaps compare "git --version" with "sudo git --version".

Comment: Yes you were right indeed. 1.7.1 vs 2.5.1 when i compiled from source, must have missed to install for all users.